# Why the change function is not called in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi I have the code to called the function on change the value of input field.where i just implement the jquery mobile datepicker but internally its change to

```
<input type="text" data-role="date" style="width:100%" class="to hasDatepicker" id="To" name="To">
```

(means adding hasdatepicker to that input field)So that It is not working .But when i change to click function it is working fine what might be the problem can any body tell and how to achieve that?

```html
$('input.to').on('change',function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

"To" is the id not a class, selector should be:

```
$('#To').on('change',function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing element by class name but `To` is not a class.

```
$('input[id=To]').on('change',function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

As the above said, "To" is an id name, If you are insisting on using the `(Element.Attribute)` style I'd recommend to use `$('input#To').on('clicked',function()).` 
You could also use `$('input#To').clicked(function())` or just `$("#To")` which is preferred, since Id is an element Unique. You usually is the `(Element.Attribute)` style when you have a couple of elements, say `<input></input>` and you want to select a particular input by it's class, and not all the `<input></input>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to see how you are including the jQuery import. If you are including correctly, maybe have somewhere a function that killing your change. Verify whether have another call to this same event or a call to $('input.to').off('click') somewhere. But you can also call this method using $('#To').

Comment: Remember that change is trigged when you write in the input and lost the focus.